# IE and "disabled" in "<link>" properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a jQuery stylesheet switcher to switch between three stylesheets, each three of these stylesheets include `@media print {}` to control the print styles for each three stylesheets.

The stylesheet references are as follows

```
<link title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/default_style.css" />
<link title="alternate" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/mono_style.css" />   
<link title="acrf" rel="acrf stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/acrf_style.css" />
```

And the control for these are as follows:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-fw"></i> Default Theme</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-fw"></i> Monochrome Theme</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('acrf'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-fw"></i> aCRF mode</a></li>
```

If I select default style this is what happens to the stylesheet references in Chrome and Firefox (I can see this actively happening on both developer consoles

```
<link title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/default_style.css" />
<link title="alternate" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/mono_style.css" disabled/>   
<link title="acrf" rel="acrf stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/acrf_style.css" disabled/>
```

However in Internet Explorer `disabled` doesn't get inserted into the  references - The style of the pages **does change in Internet Explorer** however when printing it ignores all of the print styles and just prints every single piece of HTML.

The set up works perfectly on screen and on print in both Firefox and Chrome, it's just Internet Explorer that produces the problem, I believe the issue is that `<link disabled>` isn't recognised by Internet Explorer (I'm using Version 10 and tried compatibility mode).

Does anyone have any idea as to how to resolve this issue? Please let me know if you require any more information or code snippets.

Here is the JS that controls the styleswitching

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title)
{
var i, a, main;
for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
    if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
        a.disabled = true;
        if (a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
}
}

function getActiveStyleSheet()
{
var i, a;
for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
    if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
}
return null;
}

 function getPreferredStyleSheet()
{
var i, a;
for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
    if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
}
return null;
}

function createCookie(name, value, days)
{
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else expires = "";
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name)
{
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
}
return null;
}

window.onload = function(e)
{
var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e)
{
var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see this  http://www.paulund.co.uk/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks @111 but this is a question about a potential bug, not re-writing the styleswitcher system unless needed.  I also have cookies set to remember which style the user wants to use.  This is an internal tool and the styles switch the version of the site the user wants, this isn't likely to change on a user basis so cookies are a must :)

Comment: That demo provides you another solution for jQuery stylesheet switcher and you can also add your code for cookie also in that. So You don't need to set "disabled" attribute on style sheet.